# String increment for a column of dask df

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I've tried researching but din't get any leads so posting a question,

I have a df and I want the string column values to be incremented based on their ascii values of each character of string by 3

```
df= dd.read_csv("test.csv")

print(df.head(10)) 


   Name  Age
0   Tom   10
1  Nick   15
2  Juli   14
```

Final answer should be like Name is incremented by 3 ASCII numbers

```
    Name  Age
0   Wrp    10
1   Qlfn   15
2   Myol   14
```

This action has to be carried out on a df with 10M row. Please suggest me on how to achieve this result?

If it is just a pandas df it can be carried out using the following command:

`df['Name'] = [''.join(chr(ord(s)+3) for s in i) if i is not None else None for i in df['Name']]`

If i use the same for a dask df then it throws an error `raise NotImplementedError()`

Please help me on how to write the same for a dask df.

Answer (score 1):

### I came up with the following solution, hope it serves your purpose:)

```
def ascii(name):
    result = ""
    for ch in name:
        result += chr(ord(ch) + 3)
    return result

df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(dtype=str)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(ascii)
```

Comment: it doesn't give any result. it throwing the following error `    for ch in name:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. I was saying that meta was missing so I changed your above statement to this `df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(ascii,meta=('object'))` . Let me know if I'm doing it right

Comment: You're getting type error because your dataframe corresponding to name column is not uniform, it contains the value of dtype float. I have edited the code. Let me know if that works for you.